# Liferay6.1CE Logger settings not working after server restart

Tags: logging, liferay

Liferay 6.1 CE 
dmin -> Control Panel -> Server Administration -> Log Levels - > Add Category

I have changed the ThemeLocalServiceImpl class logger information INFO to OFF and saved the settings. After saving the settings, restarted the server. The changes are not applied. I am seeing default settings ThemeLocalServiceImpl to INFO.

Please help me how to set my changes to permanent changes even after server restarts. 
FYI: i am using tomcat 7.0 server

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design: Any changes to log levels that are made through the UI *will* be reverted to the static configuration upon restarting the server. You'll need to go into the log4j configuration files and configure Liferay accordingly if you want the changes to survive a restart. Typically those changes are done in order to quickly debug issues and rather than filling up logfiles for eternity, this behaviour was chosen to be more disk-space friendly.

E.g. find log4j.properties in Liferay's `WEB-INF/classes`